# Lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, operadores

Obtenho este erro

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

no código

```
if (a*a = b*b + c*c) {
    printf ("TRIANGULO RETANGULO\n");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer fazer uma comparação, certo? Então use o operador correto para comparações e não use o operador de atribuição:

```
if (a * a == b * b + c * c) printf("TRIANGULO RETANGULO\n");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/Equals.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado!